# What is the recommended way to schedule azure jobs for SSIS packages

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-scheduler

If i am not **wrong** Azure Portal Database not have The SQL Agent.My azure database Integration Service Catalogs is bellow. What is the recommended way to schedule SSIS routine jobs.
[image]

What is the recommended way to schedule routine jobs? Is it possible in Azure ?

Comment: is this a VM or SQL Azure? is it possible for you to schedule a job as it is done in on-prem MSSQL?

Comment: @ Isham Mohamed I have portal.azure not any VM.

Comment: How do you even get a SSIS catalog in SQL Azure DB? As far as I know this is not supported. Are you 100% certain this is not a VM?

Comment: Interesting... so this is now supported. Following @Alberto link yields this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-schedule-packages

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you can also follow Sreedhar-Pelluru link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Azure Data Factory as stated on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-lift-shift-ssis-packages-overview) official documentation.some more info

Azure Data Factory hosts the runtime engine for SSIS packages on Azure. The runtime engine is called the Azure SSIS Integration Runtime (SSIS IR).

When you provision the SSIS IR, you can scale up and scale out by specifying values for the following options:

- The node size (including the number of cores) and the number of nodes in the cluster.
- The existing instance of Azure SQL Database to host the SSIS Catalog Database (SSISDB), and the service tier for the database.
  The maximum parallel executions per node.